# App not finding Razor page located in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm working on Razor Pages Project. This solution consists of multiple projects, namely "Server", which manages services for dependency injection and is a startup project. "App" which contains Index page and shared Components, and multiple "Module" projects that are independent areas of a site. I need to add new module to this solution, with landing page. I created new project, set all references to other projects in solution, and created a page there with "@page "/moduleC"" line. But if I run solution and go to that page - it shows 404 page. Same configuration works fine with other modules. Is there some additional actions required to allow routing between multiple projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are working on Blozor app. If my guess is correct , please import the reference inside the **_Import.razor** in your Balzor.WebAssembly or Balzor.Server project.

Example

> @using <--ProjectName-->.ComponentsLibrary
> @using <--ProjectName-->.ComponentsLibrary.<--ComponentName-->

Comment: I do work on Blazor app, and I already added reference to my project in _Imports page

Comment: @JohnDiGriz, In my sample app I am able navigate to the SharedComponents page using `NavLink` and also by using `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` also direcly by changing the route in the broswer URL. not sure what exactly your issue is. Try to debug it by Keeping the brakpoints in _App.razor also in the new component. Try clearing cache and delete the browser history and run the app.

Comment: can you walk me the steps? Because I tried to create sample app but problem still there. Maybe I forgetting something else

Comment: @JohnDiGriz
Below are the steps I followed
* Created Map component in SharedComponentsProject
* Added the reference in the _Imports.razor
* Created new  razor component in UI project and used the name of the component inside the newly created component and mentioned `@page <--url-->`
* Added NavLink in navigation page and mentioned the path

Scenario 2
* Added a button in Home component  in the event mentioned `NavigationManger with path` of the component which i want to redirect

Both the case worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly I did, but after messing with it for a few days it started working normally. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

https://digitteck.com/frontend/blazor/blazor-page-in-another-assembly/

The Router component is responsible for mapping the razor pages.

You will need to add the other assemblies using the AdditionalAssemblies parameter.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="@_extraAssemblies">
        <Found Context="routeData">
           ...
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            ...
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code{

    private List<System.Reflection.Assembly> _extraAssemblies = new List<System.Reflection.Assembly>()
    {
        typeof(OtherProject.SomeObjectInOtherProject).Assembly,
    };

}
```

Comment: In my case, this was exactly what I needed.