Blazor pages in a seperate project Issue
I separated a page into a new Razor Components project as explained at https://digitteck.com/frontend/blazor/blazor-page-in-another-assembly/
This doesn't work until I change the following: <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> Changing this let certain pages flicker and it seems like an endless cycle. I am truly lost and hope someone encountered the same issue.
This is in .net 8

I reference the Razor Class Library which includes the shared page from the Main Blazor Project. I do not use reflection. It compiles and runs but when I access the shared page address as indicated by @page it is not found. If I add @rendermode="InteractiveServer" to it works but with issues on other pages. Did not specifically change routes.

I have updated the router as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63428712/app-not-finding-razor-page-located-in-another-project Still issues

There's simply not enough information to answer this question.  There are several things you could have done wrong, but without a view of your project ?????  Create s simple example project and publish it to GitHub.

Completely understand what you say. When I moved the problematic pages from the Account/Page folder to the my normal Components/Page folder it worked. Experienced other issues and then decided to do all in one project for now as I have limited time. My gutfeel it has something to do with MS Identity
